# What is wrong with this sqlite Update statement

Tags: sqlite, syntax, insert-update

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the update statement below

```
"UPDATE users EVENTS  (dateHash) = ('1') WHERE (id = 5)"
```

The field 'id' is of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT and 'dateHash' is of type INTEGER.

edited statement

```
"UPDATE EVENTS  (dateHash) = ('1') WHERE (id = 5)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You forgot SET**

```
UPDATE "EVENTS" SET dateHash = 1 WHERE id = 5
```

Comment: My bad, please see my new updates. But square bracket should work.

Comment: Is (users EVENTS) is a table Name?

Comment: Not sure what's going on here, when I check my table after executing the statement all the values in the dateHash column are undefined.

Comment: Hey Jade, thanks for your help turns out I had an error in the select call back I was using to check my work.